# How to call static function from another static function

Tags: c#

```
public static void func1(string a,string c)

{

func2(a,c)--- error

}

public static void func2(string a,string c)

{


}
```

if im wrong please correct it.
I need function to be called this way... function to be static.please help

Comment: Looks fine, are they in the same type?  And you are missing the semi-colon.  If the static method is in another type, you prefix the type name:  `MyType.Func2(a, b);`

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: I would bet money that the error or exception will explicitly and clearly explain what the problem is..

Comment: Two functions are related with directory
func(directoryInfo source,directoryInfo dest)
still error.

Comment: That error bears no relation to the code you've posted...

Comment: Well, if the code you've posted works, and other, unposted code doesn't work - I can only guess it's because you've got two methods with the same signature?

Comment: Missing ";" ...and methods not declared inside a class :P

Comment: Hints for getting useful answers quickly: 1) Post complete code. 2) If there's an error, post the error message.

Answer (score 3):

Is the error a missing semicolon? The lack of error message makes this a guessing game.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with that. Forgot ";"?

Or your names are in conflict with already used ones. Try changing them and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anything wrong with the code snippet you have added, Can you give some more details on namespace for these functions